# If someone logs out of my iTunes can I still track my iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

My iPod 5 was recently stolen and I have downloaded the "Find My iPhone" app and I logged into my iTunes account to track all the devices using it. It says my iPod 5 is currently offline and will notify me once it connects to the internet. I've also set it on lost mode so when it connects it will change my passcode. If someone has logged out if my iTunes and into their own, will it still track it as mine? Or will it just not show the device on the app at all? Because I don't want to have this app for nothing if it isn't tracking my stolen iPod.

Comment: Please use the search button on this site. There are many duplicates of this question around.

Comment: I don't feel like looking through millions of questions. I don't have time for that.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-my-iphone

Comment: none of those are the same question as mine?

Answer (score 0):

If someone logs you out of your primary iCloud account (the one used for Find My iPhone) on the device, you will no longer be able to track it.

Note that removing Find My iPhone from a device requires your current iCloud password — you can't remove it without knowing the password to your iCloud account.

Comment: So if they do log out on the Find-My-iPhone app my iPod won't even show up?

Comment: @user81759 This is correct, but does require your password to log out.

Comment: If they have my password and log out, it won't even show up? I'm sorry I'm asking so many questions it just shows that it is offline and I don't wanna be waiting on an iPod that it won't track if they've logged out lol.

Comment: @user81759 Correct, deleted devices leave no trace on Find My iPhone. You will receive an email though.